# How to fix Livewire Pagination?

Tags: pagination, laravel-livewire

My livewire was worked before but after page refresh. now my pagination, cart, product upload specially livewire any action is not working. i updated my Xampp Php version from 7.3 to 7.4 but still not working. please help me.

Comment: "Not working" without any errors, description or code, makes it impossible for us to actually help you.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/null/vendor/livewire/livewire.js?id=21fa1dd78491a49255cd i found this error now. how to solve it.

Comment: here is the live link: http://ecom.rtdoutsourcingbd.com/ shop page, cart page pagination on reload was worked before but now none of them are working. Even add new category, edit category was worked with auto slug. but nothing are working now. i solved the JS not found problem but please help me anyone from that live URL. Admin user: admin@gmail.com pass: 12345678

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself. it was a HTML command at the top of that page and bottom also when i removed these and finally these pages working fine. i also test it while i add the Command tag back again it was not worked. So this is the solution.